# Limit possibilities for Mapbox Directions API

Tags: javascript, api, mapbox, directions, transit

I don't have much knowledge of Javascript and I haven't been able to figure out a solution for my problem. I'm making use of the Mapbox Direction API, which currently supports traffic/driving/walking/cycling. I am however interest in an other option; transit, for which I have my own GTSF datasets up and running in a queryable database. Hence; I want to use the code of the Mapbox Direction API and couple it to my own database (in the end, some small steps first..). 
- Example: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-directions/
- Code: https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-directions/v3.1.1/mapbox-gl-directions.js

Does anyone know how (easily) I can edit the Javascript in such a way that; the Start and Destination can ónly be selected based from a pre-defined list.

*PS: If anyone has any other idea of creating a javascript layover with a simple list-based Point A to Point B which returns a text-based popup/layover, on mapbox... let me know.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
Disable map-based selections:

```
    /*case types.ORIGIN_FROM_COORDINATES:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    originQueryCoordinates: action.coordinates
  });*/

/*case types.DESTINATION_FROM_COORDINATES:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    destinationQueryCoordinates: action.coordinates
  });*/
```

--

```
var MapboxDirections = function () {
function MapboxDirections(options) {
_classCallCheck(this, MapboxDirections);

this.actions = (0, _redux.bindActionCreators)(actions, store.dispatch);
this.actions.setOptions(options || {});
this.options = options || {};

this.onDragDown = this._onDragDown.bind(this);
this.onDragMove = this._onDragMove.bind(this);
this.onDragUp = this._onDragUp.bind(this);
this.move = this._move.bind(this);
//this.onClick = this._onClick.bind(this);
}
```

To get my own transit-based list I need to create my own database with searchable Json files, as set-up in Mapbox's own API: api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places. This is a different question, and I will therefore open a new topic.